# json_encode Change My Array Into stdClass Object, Is This Normal?

Tags: php, json

I have this code :

```
<?php

$array = array ( array ('pcs'=>'23', 'kg'=>'3'),
                 array ('pcs'=>'24', 'kg'=>'4'),
                 array ('pcs'=>'25', 'kg'=>'5'));

echo '<pre>';

print_r($array);

$array = json_encode($array);

echo $array;

$array = json_decode($array);

echo '<pre>';

print_r($array);
?>
```

and here's the output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pcs] => 23
            [kg] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pcs] => 24
            [kg] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pcs] => 25
            [kg] => 5
        )

)
[{"pcs":"23","kg":"3"},{"pcs":"24","kg":"4"},{"pcs":"25","kg":"5"}]
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pcs] => 23
            [kg] => 3
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pcs] => 24
            [kg] => 4
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pcs] => 25
            [kg] => 5
        )

)
```

why my array becomes `stdClass Object`? can I still manipulates `stdClass Object` just like an array?

UPDATE : I got this error when I tried to echo-ing `$array[0]['pcs']` :

```
Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/*** on line **
```

Comment: you can more or less iterate through a stdClass object like you would an array though if you prefer the array syntax and structure use `json_decode( $data, true );` to force output as an array

Comment: I advise you to read a manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "problem" has nothing in common with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), but rather with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

This will return an array:

`$array = json_decode($array, true);`

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> json_decode() is use to Decodes a `JSON` string:

When you use second param as `TRUE` in `json_decode()`:

> Returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

**Solution for you:**

```
$array = json_decode($array,TRUE); // use second param as TRUE in your code.
```

---

**Some Basic Examples for Understanding:**

**Example 1:**

```
<?php
$json = '{"test":"test","test2":"test2"}'; // json string

echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($json)); // without using second param    
?>
```

**Result (return as object):**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [test] => test
    [test2] => test2
)
```

**Example 2:**

```
<?php
$json = '{"test":"test","test2":"test2"}';

echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($json,TRUE)); // with second param true    
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [test] => test
    [test2] => test2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's standard php behavior. `json_decode()` will convert incoming data to an array of objects of class `stdClass`.

You can still access all elements but you have to do it more OOP:

```
echo $array[0]->pcs;
echo $array[0]->kg;
```

If you want `json_decode()` to reproduce your initial array use second option of the function:

```
$array = json_decode($array, true);
echo $array[0]['pcs'];
echo $array[0]['kg'];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this Normal?

**Yes**, because `json_decode` basically returns an object and since you didn't specify the second parameter it should return an object and not an array.

[According to docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

so to make it return an array, is to make the second parameter equal to  true.

```
$array = json_decode($array,true);
```